# Dynamically ignore the properties on class using json.net

Tags: .net, json

Is it possible to tell dynamically to ignore the property using JsonIgnore?
As json message sometimes need to ignore a field.
For example

```
Class A  {
[JsonProperty("Random1")]
public string somerandomfield1 {get; set;}
[JsonProperty("Random2")]
public string somerandomfield2 {get; set;}
}
```

However sometimes Class A needs to ignore field "somerandomfield1" while building a json message.

```
Class A {
[JsonIgnore]
public string somerandomfield1 {get; set;}
[JsonProperty("Random2")]
public string somerandomfield2 {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json.NET has the ability to conditionally serialize properties by placing a ShouldSerialize method on a class.

the following link will give details
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm